# Array variable "might not have been initialized"

Tags: java

I get the error:

> TestCounter.java:115: variable
>   counters might not have been
>   initialized
>          counters[i] = new Counter(i);

And I can't figure out how to fix it. I know that my class, `Counter`, works. Below is my code, if you could have a look at it I would be very happy. This code is wrapped in the main method of a `TestCounter` class.

```
  if(success) 
  {  
   Counter[] counters;

   for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
   {
       counters[i] = new Counter(i);
       System.out.println(counters[i].whatIsCounter());
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You haven't created the array, you've just declared the variable.

You need to do this:

```
Counter[] counters = new Counter[30];
```

or something similar

Comment: that worked, but is there a way in which I can create an array of arbitrary size? I thought that's what I did when I declared it :/

Comment: @Calle: No. Arrays in java are fixed-size. If you want a a variable-length sequence, then use a `List` collection, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `counters` array.
Something like this:

```
if(success) 
  {  
   Counter[] counters=new Counters[30];

   for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
   {
       counters[i] = new Counter(i);
       System.out.println(counters[i].whatIsCounter());
   }
  }
```

By stating `Counter[] counters` you are not actually creating an array, you are simple declaring a reference variable `counters` of type `Counter[]`.

`Counter[] counters=new Counters[30]` will create an array of type `Counter` of size 30 with each element holding null reference.