# How to initialize an array inside a if statement in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I tried to initialize in the below way but the compiler throws the error "variable **aa**  and **bb** might not have been initialized"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CompatibleArrays{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i=0,aa[];
        System.out.println("Enter the size for First array:");
        int a = myObj.nextInt();
        if(a>0){
            aa = new int[a];
            System.out.println("Enter the elements for First array:");
            for(i=0;i<a;i++){
                aa[i]=myObj.nextInt();
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid array size");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't produce any errors.

Comment: There is no `bb` in this code. Please share your _actual_ code that produces the warning.

Comment: Sorry, besides some poorly named variables your codes seems to work.

Comment: This: should answer your question: [Array variable "might not have been initialized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172274/array-variable-might-not-have-been-initialized). The problem arises when `a<=0`, in which case `aa` never gets assigned any value (note: it's not `null`, but nothing/undefined, which does not work in Java). Move the declaration of `aa` into the `if` case, or initialize is with `null` or an empty array before the if statement.

Comment: Thank you Malte Hartwig, I initialized **aa={}**,and it worked fine, but when I tried to declare **aa** inside the if statement it threw error **Variable declaration not allowed here**, why is that so?